# Tomcat 8 and Java Web Sockets ClassCastException

Tags: java, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, tomcat8

I am trying to implement the following Websockets example in a Spring 4.0 Web applications:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

I have the following config file:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket/init").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Here is the JavaScript I am using on the client with SockJS and Stomp.js:

```
    var stompClient = null;

    var socket = new SockJS('/HR/socket/init');

    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {

        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

        stompClient.send("/HR/get/staff", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'country': 'United Kingdom', 'city': 'London' }));

        stompClient.subscribe('/HR/new/staff', function(message){

            console.log(message);

        });

    });
```

When the socket connection is created I am receiving a class cast exception as below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer
```

I have seen the same issue on another StackOverflow question, unfortunately the solution did not solve my problem as I am not including the javax.websocket-api in my build.gradle file. I have tried including it and excluding it and I get the same error. I am using Tomcat 8.0.14.

**Note:** The exact same code base has been testing with Java 7 on Tomcat 7 and it works. When I change over to Java 8 and run it on Tomcat 8 I get the exception above.

Comment: Does the spring guide work with tomcat 7 and Java 7?
Could you paste here your gradle file?